# Error in accessing page element in java script

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

**Compiler Error Message:** CS0117: 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.RadioButton' does not contain a definition for **'ClientId'**

**ASP Code**

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="rdo_SelectAllCompany" Checked="true" Text="Select All" 
onClick="javascript:chk_CompanySelectDeselectAll_Changed();"
GroupName="a" runat="server" />
```

**JavaScript function**

```
function chk_CompanySelectDeselectAll_Changed()
{
    var checkStatus=document.getElementById(<%=rdo_SelectAllCompany.ClientId %>").checked;
    if (checkStatus)
    {
        var ListViewObject=document.getElementById("<%=Lst_Company.ClientID %>");
        for(var j=0;j<ListViewObject.options.length;j++)
        {
            ListViewObject.options[j].selected=true;
        }
        document.getElementById("<%=Lst_Company.ClientId %>").disabled=true;
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("<%=Lst_Company.ClientId %>").disabled=false;
        var ListViewObject=document.getElementById("<%=Lst_Company.ClientID %>");
        for(var j=0;j<ListViewObject.options.length;j++)
        {
            ListViewObject.options[j].selected=false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `ClientId` !== `ClientID` - you seem to use them interchangeably - which wont work

Comment: Thanks ...error solved